# Getting Irish visa/work permit with EU residence permit?

Tags: visa, working-visas, eu, eu-citizens, ireland

I am a EU Citizen(Finland). My husband is having **permanent** residence permit in Finland.Now he got a job in Ireland.Does he need visa/work permit to work in Ireland?
Does My EU citizenship help him to move to Ireland?

Comment: Yes, you can move to Ireland with your husband under EU freedom of movement and your husband will have the right to work in Ireland.  I am not sure exactly how this works if you are "economically inactive" and dependent on your husband's income, however.  Someone ought to come along with some pointers in the near future.  I don't think that your husband's Finnish permanent residence gives him an independent right to establish himself in another EU country.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it would be a bit tricky. First of all, the Finnish residence permit has no power in Ireland because Ireland isn't in Schengen.

But there is a way. You, as a EU citizen, should move into Ireland and declare Irish residence to tax purposes. Then, your spourse might apply for an Irish residence permit. It is Stamp 4EUFam for the case. [The details](http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/EU%20Treaty%20Rights)